# How to remove unwanted architecture x86_64 from Xcode build?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to recompile someone else's code. The code includes a reference to a third party library myLib.a, which has two slices:

```
Architectures in the fat file: myLib.a are: armv7 arm64
```

I get this warning, following by a bunch of link errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file myLib.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file myLib.a (2 slices)
```

Now, I know this library is not intended to work in a simulator. So I want to throw the simulator away from build. I don't really understand build targets, so I did this:

[image]

Still, same error. What am I doing wrong?

Xcode 7.3

Comment: try adding armv7s or armv6s

Comment: Tried adding armv7s. Now it says " file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)". Hmm... what's going on? Why would adding armv7s have this effect?

Comment: i think u r trying on simulator. try on device. or delete Derived Data and clean project

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say I am trying on simulator. I am doing Product > Clean, then Product > Build. Is it what you meant? This is a remote computer, macincloud.com, so trying it on device is not easy, but I certainly want to turn off the simulator.

Comment: Tried deleting derived data, same result

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65307436/5303139

Answer (score 3):

I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65307436/5303139

**Same anwser**

For an iOS project, you have the following architectures: `arm64` `armv7` `armv7s` `i386` `x86_64`

`x86_64`, `i386` are used for the simulator.

What could be your problem is the framework you are using was build for iOS and not a simulator.

To fix this issue you can bypass the build framework and use lipo command lines.

**First**: `lipo -info [The library.framework location]`

**Example Usage** : `lipo -info /Users/.../library.framework/LibrarySDK`

**Example output** :

```
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/.../library.framework/LibrarySDK are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64
```

You will get the list of architecture used for that framework.

**Second**: we need to strip the framework from the simulator architecture and make 2 versions of that framework (1 is used for iOS Device and 1 for the simulator)

**using**:  `lipo -remove [architecture] [location] -o [output_location]`

**Example**: `lipo -remove i386 /Users/.../SDK -o /Users/.../SDK_Output_Directory`

Go to your chosen output directory to get the new generated SDK without the removed architecture to verify you can use the lipo -info command same as above

You can use the same lipo remove command on the newly created SDK but with another architecture
`lipo -remove x86_64 ...` and you will get an SDK only for iOS devices

**Third**: Take that final SDK and rename it "SDK_Name_IOS" and use it.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

You did set architect to armv7, arm64 so just change Build Active Architecture Only to YES in debug mode:

debug mode: YES

release mode: NO (default value)

So when debug you will build only for current device

Comment: Also, is i86_64 used in release mode? If not (and I would think not), how is it removed, and can I do the same with debug mode? Alternatively, can I remove debug mode altogether? Do I have any benefit from debug mode at all, running online?

Comment: why is it even trying to do that (simulator) while I am trying to build an archive?

Comment: Hey larva!!, thanks man , you made my day great!!! :)

Comment: `just change Build Active Architecture Only to YES` this work for me