# IPA Processing Failed: Could not resolve @executable_path

Tags: ios, xcode12, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am stuck with this error when exporting IPA.
I did refer similar questions and none of them worked for me.

I am migrating my project from carthage to SPM, most of the frameworks which I use support SPM and only two had XCFrameworks.

Have added XCFrameworks with Embed & Sign, and earlier I used to have the simulator architectures removal script, with XCFrameworks I have removed that from my build phase step now.

When looked in the standard log I could not spot any error when searched with "fail"
Is there anything in the standard log which would indicate an error which I should be looking for ?

EDIT: Before you close as Duplicate of [How to fix "IPA processing failed" error in xcode 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382217/how-to-fix-ipa-processing-failed-error-in-xcode-11)

Please check this is for Xcode 12 with SPM & XCFrameworks !

[image]

The only errors I can spot in the logs are below:

```
2021-02-10 09:37:47 +0000  Scanning IPA...
2021-02-10 09:37:50 +0000  warning: Failed to resolve rpath for **SDK: Could not resolve @executable_path for @executable_path/Frameworks from **SDK
2021-02-10 09:37:50 +0000  warning: Failed to resolve rpath for ***: Could not resolve @executable_path for @executable_path/Frameworks from ***
```

But when I compared with the logs from another project with similar set up, I can see the same set of "warnings" and I am able to generate IPA on the another project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "IPA processing failed" error in xcode 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382217/how-to-fix-ipa-processing-failed-error-in-xcode-11)

Comment: I need bitcode to be enabled, most of them suggest to disable that. Rest answers are for stripping frameworks, but as I mentioned i dont use frameworks but XCFrameworks.

Comment: Add logs to your question, to make it more specific

Comment: You should add your logs in your question.